# How do I mock a repository in jasmine to trigger the THEN in this code block?

Tags: javascript, angular, jasmine

I'm trying to increase code coverage in my project by performing simple jasmine tests on basic methods. In my controller, I have this:

```
function fetchStates() {
            $repository.states().all().then(function(data) {
                vm.states = data;
            });
        }
```

I'm trying to set vm.states, but absolutely nothing I've tried will get that THEN to fire. I can mock a repository such that jasmine doesn't complain that it doesn't exist, but when i try to run controller.fetchStates(); it simply will not get to that inner line of code. What's the correct way to mock $repository.states().all().then so that it will allow vm.states = data?

```
 function GetMockFacRepo() {
        var facilityPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            resolve({ id: 1 });
        });
        return {
            states: function () {
                return {
                    id: 0,
                    all: function () {
                        then:
                        {
                            return facilityPromise
                        }
                    }
                    
                }
            }
        };
    }
```

```
var repo2 = GetMockFacRepo();
spyOn(repo2.states.all, "then").and.callFake(function () { return 1 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
 function GetMockFacRepo() {
        var facilityPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            resolve({ id: 1 });
        });
        return {
            states: function () {
                return {
                    id: 0,
                    all: function() {
                       // return facilityPromise here so .then works
                       return facilityPromise;
                    }
                    
                }
            }
        };
    }
```

You also maybe have to wait for the promise to resolve before asserting `vm.states = data;`. In Angular 2+, you can use `fakeAsync/tick` and `fixture.whenStable()`. I am not sure what you can use in Angular 1.

Comment: Might be worth noting that the `then:` in the OP's code is being parsed as a [label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label) instead of what they probably thought.

Comment: I've refactored the repo so that it does this. However, it's still not going into function(data) {
                vm.states = data;
            }

Answer (score 0):

It ended up being a combination of explicitly mocking the repository, creating my own promise instead of using q, *and* calling the controller constructor with async.

repo code:

```
var mockRepo = {
            states: function () {
                return {
                    all: function () {                        
                        var items = [];
                        var i = 0;
                        for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                            items.push(i);
                        }
                        var sectionPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                            resolve(items);
                        });                        
                        return sectionPromise;
                    }
                }
            },
}
```

Test:

```
 describe('POC', function () {
        beforeEach(async function () {
            controller = createController();
        });
        it('POC', function () {
            expect(controller.states.length).toEqual(5);
            
        });       
    });
```

EDIT: The controller calls the method that populates the states property internally, I don't have to call it explicitly to get the property populated